# kivy: how to run loop function when screen switches without hanging screen?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

**What I am trying to achieve:** when the screen switches from ScreenOne to ScreenTwo, run a 'while loop' function until a button on ScreenTwo is pressed and breaks the loop.

This function is supposed to run and receive inputs from a barcode scanner attached to my computer (Meaning, the inputs are the barcodes) and updates the label on ScreenTwo with the number of barcode scanned.

Then once I have no more barcode to scan, press "Done" button on ScreenTwo - and that is supposed to send input "999" to break the loop function.

**How I tried to run function when screen switches:** using 'on_enter'

```
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def on_enter(self):
        getStatus()
        updatePoints()
```

**Issue I am facing:**

1. The screen switches from ScreenOne to ScreenTwo, and the function runs (I see it happening on the Mac terminal) **BUT** the buttons on ScreenTwo can't be pressed (Mac colour wheel spins).
2. And I have not figured out how to have the "Done" button send input '999' to the function to break the loop.

**How do I resolve 1?**

**How do I achieve 2?**

Here are Screenshots of the ScreenOne and ScreenTwo respectively:
[image: Screenshot of ScreenOne]
[image: Screenshot of ScreenTwo]

---

Here's the returnStation2.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


def getStatus():
    while True:
        answer = input('What is the box ID? ')
        if answer == 999: #LOOPS BREAK WHEN INPUT IS 999
            break
        elif type(answer) == int:
            do something
        else:
            print('Sorry I did not get that')

def updatePoints():
    do something

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_one = ObjectProperty(None)
    screen_two = ObjectProperty(None)

class ScreenOne(Screen):
    member_status = ObjectProperty(None)

    def backspace(self, textString):
        newTextString = textString[0:-1]
        self.display.text = newTextString

    def getPoints(self, phoneNumber):
        self.manager.screen_two.member_status.text = phoneNumber

class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    input_text = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_enter(self):
        getStatus()
        updatePoints()

    def clearField(self):
        self.manager.screen_one.input_text.text = ""

class ReturnStationLayout2App(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReturnStationLayout2App().run()
```

Here is the returnStationLayout2.kv

The "Done" button (in ScreenTwo) is at the bottom of the script.

It can't be pressed when the screen is switched to ScreenTwo.
And I hope that when pressed, it can input '999' to break the loop function that is running.

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_one: screen_one
    screen_two: screen_two

    ScreenOne:
        id: screen_one
        name: 'menu'
    ScreenTwo:
        id: screen_two
        name: 'settings'

<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

<ScreenOne>:
    input_text : entry
    GridLayout:
        id: numberPad
        rows: 5
        padding: [300,200]
        spacing: 10

        # Where input is displayed
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: "+65"
                font_size: 50
                size_hint: 0.2, 1
            TextInput:
                id: entry
                font_size: 50
                multiline: False
                padding: [20, ( self.height - self.line_height ) / 2]


        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            CustButton:
                text: "1"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "2"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "3"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "DEL"
                on_press: root.backspace(entry.text)

        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            CustButton:
                text: "4"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "5"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "6"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "AC"
                on_press: entry.text = ""

        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            CustButton:
                text: "7"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "8"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "9"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            CustButton:
                text: "Enter" #HERE IS THE ENTER BUTTON
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.transition.duration = 1
                    root.manager.current = 'settings'
                    root.getPoints(entry.text)

        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 10
            Label:
                text: ""
            CustButton:
                text: "0"
                on_press: entry.text += self.text
            Label:
                text: ""
            Label:
                text: ""

<ScreenTwo>:
    member_status: memberStatus
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: memberStatus
            text: ''  
        GridLayout:
            rows: 3
            padding: [100,500]
            spacing: 10
            BoxLayout:
                Label:
                    text: "You have scanned:"
            BoxLayout:
                CustButton:
                    text: "Done" #THIS IS THE BUTTON I HOPE TO BE ABLE TO BREAK THE LOOP FUNCTION
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                        root.manager.current = 'menu'
                        root.clearField()
```

Comment: Once you start while loop, it will keep going untill you break it, and block all of the other behaviour. Meaning, you will not be able to click the button while the code is running, and you will not be able to update the screen. You could try making a separate thread independant from other parts of your application, but I believe Python's `input()` will block everything due to the way it's created (I would appreciate someone backing me up on this). Apart from that, when I ran your code the button was covered by other elements, and I had to first change your grid layout's padding to [100, 100].

Comment: It's possible to call a function every n seconds using kivy's  [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html), as well as use kivy's [`TextInput`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) for input (to not use the `input()`). Would that be enough to solve your problem?

Comment: @Kacper Floriański is there any way for the loop to listen to inputs from both the screen (buttons) and my barcode scanner? What I wanna achieve is a user is about to scan any number of barcodes (that's why the loop to listen to more inputs if any), and once he is done scanning, press the done button and break out of the loop. Is there any way to go about it?

Comment: The easiest way would be to add an "Add" button that has to be pressed to add the barcode. Note that even using python's `input()` requires you to press enter after each input. If barcodes are entered from keyboard, you could ask the user to enter them all in a specific format, and simply extract the values from there. If they are graphical objects, you could make it without any button press for example by making the user have to wait for 1 second without moving their phone for the barcode to be scanned.

Comment: @KacperFloriański I'm thinking of the a library borrow kiosk. How does it allow user to scan any number of books they intend to borrow then click "done" on the kiosk's screen to process the borrowing of all the books that have been scanned?

Comment: Or is it possible to run a function when an input is detected? because my barcode scanner sends an "enter" signal after each scan, we don't have to manually press "enter" after each input.

Comment: No idea, I don't use that type of service myself and I couldn't see any  barcodes on videos I found on youtube, I presume the technology behind the scanning are [RFID tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification).

Comment: Like I've mentioned before, you could learn how to use kivy's [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) and attempt to scan a tag every n seconds, for example every 0.01 seconds, in which case you would also need to check if a given barcode was already scanned, to avoid having the same barcode scanned many times. This will behave like a while loop without stopping your code. However, a new problem will appear if your scanning function is noticeably slow.

Comment: @KacperFloriański Yes you are right, they are RFID tags, but even then, the RFID reader is able to pick up the tags and users are able to click "end" to stop the reading. 

Other than the clock method, is there a way to accept screen buttons as input? so they kinda work like a keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

This answer is based on discussion in comments section present under the question. The code below is written under an assumption that the scanner sends a specific signal when a barcode is scanned. The overall idea is to run a function after that signal was sent.

## Clock cycle

I suggest getting familiar with kivy's [Clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html) object. It is possible to create a listener function that would check if the signal was sent every n seconds. Precisely, let's say you want to run `process()` function once a signal was detected. Let's also declare a variable `scanned` to store information if a barcode was succesfully scanned and create a listener to check if the signal was sent (so check if the `scanned` variable holds `True`). Following code sample sets the `scanned` variable every 2 seconds to `True` to mimic the scanning behaviour.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

# Define constants and the scanned variable, for easy example
INTERVAL = 0.01
scanned = False


# Process method runs every 0.01 seconds, note the use of dt argument (explained in docs)
def process(dt):
    # Retrieve the global variable, for easy example
    global scanned
        
    # Check if scanned, note setting scanned to False once an item was scanned.
    # Here you can also check the uniqueness of the scanned barcode (to avoid having the same barcode processed many times)
    if scanned is True:
        print("Scanned! Processing the data and setting scanned to False.")
        scanned = False
    else:
        print("Not scanned yet!")


# Mimic scanning behaviour
def scan(dt):
    # Retrieve the global variable and set it to true 
    global scanned
    scanned = True


class Main(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        
        # Schedule the functions to be called every n seconds
        Clock.schedule_interval(process, INTERVAL)
        Clock.schedule_interval(scan, INTERVAL*200)

    def build(self):
        # Display screen with a single button for easy example
        scr = Screen()
        btn = Button(text="You can press me but nothing will happen!")
        scr.add_widget(btn)
        return scr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Output:

```
Not scanned yet!
.
.
.
Not scanned yet!
Scanned! Processing the data and setting scanned to False.
```

Comment: May I ask, so during the intervals, the buttons on the screen will still be functioning? can they still be pressed on?

Comment: Yes, they will still be functioning. Let me edit the answer and add a button.

Comment: I've included the button to show that the app will stay responsive.

Comment: WOW GREAT! I think this will work for my application :)) i will try to see how to put it into my code. I am so bad at this :/ but thanks for helping me out thus far! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries, I really like the idea of your project, keep up the good job :)

Comment: One more question. How does input() come in here? cos I still need to ask for input to process the barcode that's scanned. and it just hangs there if no input is detected :/

Comment: Just create a [`TextInput`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html) for it (you can display it in your GUI and process for example once enter was clicked).